# One drive access in 21.10

Tags: online-accounts

Have also asked this in the Forums, but so far, not answered.

Recently installed 21.10, and added Google Drive and One Drive during the setup process. (Can also add these later in Settings>Online Accounts)
Have been able to find where Google drive ends up (bookmark available in Files), but can't figure out how to get to One drive, can't seem to find a link.
Anyone?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> but can't figure out how to get to One drive, can't seem to find a link. Anyone? Thanks.

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

There are only 5 reliable ways to access OneDrive on Linux:

- Via the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive - this 'syncs' your data, bi-directional operation, open source and free. Supports Personal, Business & SharePoint account types and Shared Folders. A Docker container is also available for all major architectures (x86_64, ARMHF, AARCH64)
- Via the 'onedriver' client - https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver - Native file system that only provides the OneDrive 'on-demand' functionality, open source and free. Supports Personal, Business account types. Currently does not support Shared Folders or SharePoint.
- Via 'rclone' - https://rclone.org/ - one way sync client, open source and free. Has limitations with SharePoint.
- Via non-free clients such as 'insync', 'ExpanDrive'
- Via the web browser of your choice