# Install onedrive on 22.4

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

Has anyone successfully installed one drive on 22.4?

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: see this link https://itslinuxfoss.com/install-use-onedrive-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: @jeffb - Please read https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371626/one-drive-access-in-21-10 as this gives the correct answer